# What are some other ways to prove $\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\prod_{i=1}^k\frac{n-k+i}{k-i+1}\right)=2^n-1$?

Tags: summation, alternative-proof, products

I recently discovered this identity:

> For all natural numbers n,
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\prod_{i=1}^k\frac{n-k+i}{k-i+1}\right)=2^n-1$$

I already know one way to prove it, since I derived the identity myself using the following two facts:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k} = 2^n - 1\tag{1}$$
$${n\choose {r+1}} = {n\choose r}\times\frac{n-r}{r+1}\tag{2}$$

A generalization of equation $(2)$ for ${n\choose {r+k}}$ is:
$${n\choose {r+k}} = {n\choose r}\prod_{i=1}^k\frac{n-r-k+i}{r+k-i+1}\tag{3}$$

Setting $r=0$ in equation $(3)$, we obtain:

$$\begin{align}
{n\choose k} &= {n\choose 0}\prod_{i=1}^k\frac{n-0-k+i}{0+k-i+1} \\
&=\prod_{i=1}^k\frac{n-k+i}{k-i+1}
\end{align}$$

Substituting the above expression for ${n\choose k}$ into equation $(1)$ gives us the identity. My question is: Are there alternate ways to prove this identity?

Comment: Let me know if my answer is helpful otherwise I can delete it. Bye

Comment: @gimusi It's too similar to my proof, sorry

Comment: It's ok, I thought some step was not completely clear to you. I'll delete. Thanks